# Second parameter of Router.navigate() in Angular v4?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am having trouble understanding **Router.navigate()**. Here are my questions.

1. What does Router.navigate() do?
2. How many parameters does it have?

   `Router.navigate(['search']//first, { queryParams: { query: query }}//second)`
3. What is the second parameter of Router.navigate() used for?
4. Why it is object ({ queryParams: { query: query }})?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: this is a very broad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this questions are already answered in angular documentation:

https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Comment: If your answer will only contain links to external sites, just add it as comment.

Comment: This question just can not have any other answer except direct copy & paste from documentation, which i think is completely pointless.